# What is the difference of install uwsgi from yum or pip?

Tags: pip, uwsgi, yum

I am writing some flask program. To deploy it on nginx, I am using uwsgi to do it.

First the flask program will have some code like:

```
app,host,port = myFun()
```

Then I have a wsgi config file named api.ini, the content like below (I elimited some infor):

```
chdir = ../../bin/

wsgi-file = api_uwsgi
```

The api_uwsgi is my python file generating app

After this I use command line like below to run uwsgi

```
uwsgi --ini apid.ini
```

But the problem is if the uwsig is installed by yum. The log is like below:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Mon Apr 11 13:57:30 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) on 02 January 2016 19:52:54
os: Linux-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016
nodename: ES01
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /opt/flow/etc/uwsgi
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
chdir() to ../../bin/
your processes number limit is 63466
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:8001 fd 3
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 518400 bytes (506 KB) for 16 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 28611)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 28615, cores: 4)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 28618, cores: 4)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 28622, cores: 4)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 28624, cores: 4)
*** Stats server enabled on 127.0.0.1:9191 fd: 15 ***
```

No app loaded!

Use pip install uwsgi, it will be fine and the version of uwsgi is the same. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when one installs from yum, apt or whatever package manager one uses, the distribution's uwsgi package is [fully modular](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Install.html#modular-build), so it won't install plugins for python. But installing from pip, it does that for python, since it is python's package manager after all!

If you install from yum (`yum install uwsgi`) to get it work, you also need to install the python plugin:

> `yum install uwsgi-plugin-python`

and then in your uwsgi command, you should pass `--plugin=python`